# Sorting count in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm working on a PHP/mySQL table that shows data I've put into my database, and I'm trying to make it sortable. I have two tables in my database:

Table "restaurant" has columns: ID and name

Table "item" has columns: ID, name and restaurantID (restaurantID is set to use the IDs from the "restaurant" table)

What I want to do is sort the restaurants by the number of times their ID shows up in the item table. I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this, Just haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
select r.name, count(i.ID)
from restaurant r
left join item i on i.restaurantID = r.ID
group by r.name
order by count(i.ID) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it by using a query like following;

```
SELECT restaurant.*, COUNT(items.id) AS item_id FROM restaurants, items WHERE restaurant.id = items.restaurant_id ORDER BY item_id ASC;
```

As you may know, sorting by multiple column is possible as well;

```
SELECT restaurant.*, COUNT(items.id) AS item_id FROM restaurants, items WHERE restaurant.id = items.restaurant_id ORDER BY item_id ASC, restaurant.`name` DESC;
```